# Cakephp, good ordering / sorting behaviour?

Tags: php, cakephp, sorting, behavior

Does anyone know any good ordering and sorting behaviours for cakephp?

The sort where I can have "Move Up", "Move Down", "Move to top" and "Move to bottom"?

That sort of this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [OrderedBehavior](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/orderedbehavior-2-1), it worked fine for me, don't know if it has 'move to top' and 'move to bottom' though.

Comment: Worked a treat, even had move to top and bottom :)

Answer (score 0):

If that is a tree structure you need to order use [Tree behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1351/Advanced-Usage).

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.neilcrookes.com/2009/02/09/cakephp-sequence-behavior/